# When will std::unordered_map::insert fail?

Tags: c++, c++11, insert, unordered-map

I notice that the `insert` function of `std::unordered_map` returns a `std::pair`.

The second element of the `std::pair` shows whether the value is really inserted. However, I am confused by this. Can a `std::unordered_map`, which is implemented by a hash map, fail at insertion? When will that happen?

Here is the description at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert):

> Return value
>   1-2) Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place.

Comment: You can put only unique keys in the unordered_map, unordered_set, map, or set. If the key already exists the second parameter will be set to false, and new insertion will be rejected.

Comment: The answer is literally spelled out on the same page you're quoting. -1

Comment: I have tweaked the English of your question.  It was already perfectly understandable to a native speaker, but possibly not to another non-native speaker from a different background.  Please edit it again (or just revert) if you don't understand the phrasing I have used.

Comment: In such a case it would be better to learn the meaning of the phrasing, than to revert the post to its previous, inaccurate form.

Answer (score 10):

From the same page you linked to:

> Inserts element(s) into the container, **if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key**.

(my emphasis)

In other words, the `bool` is `false` if the key was already present in the map.

Note that other failures (like an allocation failure) will be reported by an exception (and the container will be unchanged).